# If I do not define any time and distance in requestLocationUpdates(), what will happen?

Tags: android, locationmanager

If I cant pass minimum time and distance in this method, what will happen? When will this method be called?

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0, 0,locationListener);
```

Comment: Please take time to ensure your questions *can* be meaningfully answered: http://www.tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: please give me answer what happen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by setting minTime and minDistance to 0 you will get a dead phone.

[by the docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

> To
>   obtain notifications as frequently as
>   possible, set both parameters to 0.

you will just get very very rapid responses and also the battery drain on a device will be horrendous.